# Cannot create multiple test files with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jboss-arquillian

I have two files with JPA tests with Arquillian. I have notice that when I use exactly the same @Deployment method in both tests - everything is fine. But when I use different, then I get exception:

```
ArquillianServletRunner not found. Could not determine ContextRoot from ProtocolMetadata, please contact DeployableContainer developer
```

In first test file my @Deployment method looks exactly like:

```
@Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        MavenDependencyResolver resolver = DependencyResolvers.use(MavenDependencyResolver.class).loadSettings("pom.xml");

    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
            .addPackage(TestEntity1.class.getPackage()) 
            .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
            .addAsLibraries(resolver.artifact("postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901.jdbc4").resolveAsFiles());
}
```

In second test file only change is TestEntity2 instead of TestEntity1.
There is everything fine with both of my entities because I can easly use two of them in one test file.

The reason for change is to move huge number of tests to different test files.

What is wrong there? Why I cannot use multiple test files?

Comment: what  `slf4j-api` version you added?

Comment: Which Container are you running this one?

Comment: @AslakKnutsen
I use arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1

Comment: @singhakash
I didn't specify version explicitly